# Get First Value From JS Map

Tags: javascript, arrays, mapping, map-function

I have this code mapping through an array of JS objects

```
 marketplaceData.map((marketplace) => {
      const { primarySaleCount, secondarySaleCount } = marketplace;
      console.log(primarySaleCount);
})
```

return values:

```
primarySaleCount -> 905, 459
secondarySaleCount -> 394, 291
```

I want to grab just one of the objects and then display them separately like this:

```
<Chart
          data={[
            [
              "Platform 1",
              parseInt(primarySaleCount),   //desiredValue -> 905. //actualValue ->905
              parseInt(secondarySaleCount), //desiredValue -> 394.  //actualValue ->392
            ],
            [
              "Platform 2",
              parseInt(primarySaleCount), //desiredValue -> 459.   //actualValue -> 905
              parseInt(secondarySaleCount), //desiredValue ->291.  //actualValue ->394
            ],

          ]}
/>
```

Basically the return value from my marketplaceData map is providing me two strings in the primarySaleCount variable. I was hoping to somehow separate the two primarySaleCount string which are being returned so I can display the two separate numbers in the different platforms in the  
(same thing goes for secondarySaleCount)

Thank You

Comment: If I understood correctly, `primarySaleCount` gives a string "905, 459" and you wanna split this into two numbers and pass each of them . similarly for `secondarySaleCount `. Is that?

Comment: yup that is corect

Comment: You can just use `split`. See the answer below

Comment: Let me know if that's what you were looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
primarySaleCount -> "905, 459"
secondarySaleCount -> "394, 291"

var primarySaleCountNumbers = primarySaleCount.split(','); //this will give you an array ['905', '459']

var secondarySaleCountNumbers= secondarySaleCount.split(',') //this will give you an array ['394', '291']
```

You can pass these in your platforms like this,

```
parseInt(primarySaleCountNumbers[0]) //To pass 905 wherever you want
parseInt(primarySaleCountNumbers[1]) //To Pass 459
```

similarly for `secondarySaleCount`

```
<Chart
          data={[
            [
              "Platform 1",
              parseInt(primarySaleCountNumbers[0]),   
              parseInt(secondarySaleCountNumbers[0]), 
            ],
            [
              "Platform 2",
              parseInt(primarySaleCountNumbers[1]), 
              parseInt(secondarySaleCountNumbers[1]),
            ],

          ]}
/>
```

Comment: Hey. I implemented that solution not working for me though I get undefined for            `parseInt(secondarySaleCountNumbers[0])`

Comment: What does your `secondarySaleCount` print?

Comment: secondarySaleCount is the same as primary just prints two numbers

Comment: Can you put it exactly here what it prints? If it prints `"394, 291"` then the above code should definitely work !

Comment: @benjamin in the earlier code, I had missed declaring the variables with ‘var’. That might be the case you getting undefined error. Updated the code. Can you check now?